# How to disable an image? Make it unclickable

Tags: html, css

How to make *img* unclickable? I want to draw something on it but when i make *mousedown* then *mousemove* image is going after my mouse. Is this possible to make it stay in place? I know that I could create it as a background in *div* but for now i want to try in img. Thanks.

Image to make it more clear because of my language:
[screen](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6421191/move.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably can solve your problem by putting this in your css :

```
#myImage {
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

EDIT (with OP's comment) :

A more complete solution would be

```
#myImage {
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
-moz-user-drag: none;
-khtml-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
user-drag: none;
}
```

(in my experience, both are needed to avoid a bad user experience)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about something like this. It helped me search and for me answer was

    -webkit-user-drag: none;

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use another div that stay in the same position to the image block which you have to set its z-index to somewhat higher than your image. For example,

```
<div id="main">
   <img src="01.jpg" alt="..." />
   <div id="draw">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#main #draw {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```